# Attempt to present UIAlertController on while a presentation is in progress

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, uialertcontroller

I am doing request in background thread, After getting response I am trying to show `UIAlertController` on main thread. But some time it is not showing `UIAlertController`.

Here is my code

```
func showAlertMessage() -> Void {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: kSuccess, message: kSuccessfullyLoggedOut, preferredStyle: .alert)

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel) { (action :UIAlertAction) in

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }

        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: It's possible you're calling `showAlertMessage` before the previous alert finished displaying (which you could know by using the completion block from the present method). This could cause that sort of behavior.

Comment: i am showing only one alert after getting response in completion block. Is this any other way to do that.

Comment: Rather than calling DispatchQueue.main.async method here, try to call that from the completion handler where you are calling showAlertMessage().

Comment: @Shabirjan , i tried that also. but i am still facing the same issue .

Comment: Did you try adding breakpoints and debug the flow of the code?

Comment: @Shabirjan, when i using break point and trying to check that time it is working properly.

Comment: I think then you are got out of the background thread i guess.

Comment: once i'll get response then only i got out from background thread. while getting response only  i am calling main thread.

Comment: I also experienced a similar problem but in my case I was displaying two alerts. I sorted the issue by showing the second alert in the completion handler of the first alert. 

Is it possible you are displaying more than one alert?